# App crashed & returned null although all the data printed correctly [ExpressJS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

I have a very strange problem, the app crashes after prints all the data correctly, the web page (view) works for the first time then stopped after reloading the page.

```
router.get('/:category/:book', function (req, res) {
    Book.findOne({slug: req.params.book}, function (bookErr, book) { 
       User.findOne({_id: book.user},function(userErr, user){

         if (bookErr || userErr) {
              console.log(bookErr, userErr);
         }
          });

                     res.render('book', {
                          b: book,
                          user: user
                         });
   }); 
  })
```

*Notes:

- When I console.log the 'req.params.book,' it's printed correctly.
- When I console.log the 'book', it's printed correctly.
- When I console.log the 'user,' it's printed correctly.
- When I go to the HTML view, all the data viewed correctly.
- The app crashed and showed the following message after page loading.
- After page reloading, the server stopped completely.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of null
    at /home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/routes/books.js:235:41
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4093:16)
    at /home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (/home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4095:12)
    at /home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
    at /home/hossam/Public/mostaml-book/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Is that a bug? & Is there a more convenient way to print these collections?

Comment: books.js is your client side javascript file?

Comment: No, it contains the routes. like: router.get('/:category/:book', function (req, res).

Answer (score 1):

I uses pure promise.Here its structure.

```
     function PromiseDemo(){
           return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{


           your first query code here
           //here dont forget to write resolve({result:'success'}); at the end of your code

   }
    return PromiseDemo().then(Response=>{
    your second query code here
    })
```

SO this is the structure of promise .You can check more abour promises here [promise is nodejs](https://www.promisejs.org/)

Comment: Sorry, I updated the code, I forget to add the res.render above. Now what the problem?

Comment: oh ok I thought that might be an issue.

Comment: @HossamBrgoth ,As we know NodeJS works on Async type .So that there is the possibility that your second find loop is executing early and then the first find query is execute so when second query executes first,that time server wont get any user so that it is giving an error.You should use aync-await or pure promise to resolve this.

Comment: So my approach is unsuitable? Could you please show me how the code in async-await?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem solved, and the solution was very strange!

In the HTML view, the image source was three points (...)!

```
<img src='...'>
```

For that, the req.params requests the book slug and then requests that the three points, and since the three points do not exist in the collection, so the result will be null.